# C# Web Client - Post UserName/Password in a dialog

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, cookies, webclient

I'm trying to use C# to automate the process of downloading files from the following website. However the problem is the site requires a login which is prompted in the form of an html dialog. I can't seem to determine a way to programmatically input the username/password.  Have tried posting them - but no joy. Any ideas?

https://transparency.entsoe.eu/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to login using a POST request and then get the response from the server of whether or not you were logged in. I found this line of code, make sure you perform the POST following how it is performed in the HTML.

```
<form id="login-form" method="POST" action="/j_spring_security_check" novalidate="novalidate">
```

Of course you must find where the "**j_spring_security_check()**" function is located in order to find where the POST is being performed if it is not posted to the same URL. From what I can tell in the HTML, the target URL for the POST request is probably stored in a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="url" id="target-url" value="/dashboard/show">
```

Make sure you try to make your post to the relative path of **/dashbord/show**

---

Also, make sure you set the variables when you make the POST request. I noticed in the HTML that you must set the following literal variables: "*password*" and "*email*".

I would help you find where the function is, but there are well over 15 javascript files to look through, and with that, I leave it to you.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a web site, I've done this using a `NetworkCredential`. Set up an Http request and add the credentials:

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
```

More reading:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential%28v=vs.110%29.aspx